# Is $\sum_{n=1}^{{\infty}}\frac{1}{P_{3n}}$ convergent?

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, prime-numbers

Is this sum below convergent? ($P_{n}$ is the nth prime.)

$$\sum_{n=1}^{{\infty}}\frac{1}{P_{3n}}$$

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{P_{3n+1}} < \frac{1}{P_{3n}}$ and $\frac{1}{P_{3n+2}} < \frac{1}{P_{3n}}$ so if this series is convergent then so is $\sum \frac{1}{P_{3n+1}}$ and $\sum\frac{1}{P_{3n+2}}$ and therefore $\sum \frac{1}{P_{3n}} + \frac{1}{P_{3n+1}} + \frac{1}{P_{3n+2}} = \sum \frac{1}{P_n}$. Do you know if this series is convergent? In not you can check out [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/386210/let-p-n-be-the-sequence-of-all-consecutive-prime-numbers-is-sum-n-geq-1?rq=1).

Comment: btw once you have solved this you can try to generalize the problem and try to show that the series $\sum \frac{1}{p_{An+B}}$ diverges for any choice of integers $A,B$. It's not that much more complicated.

Comment: And after that, that $\sum\frac1{p_{\alpha(n)}}$ diverges for any choice of the function $\alpha:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ such that $\limsup\alpha(n)/n$ is finite.

Answer (score 6):

The series 
$$\frac{1}{p_1}+\frac{1}{p_2}+\frac{1}{p_3}+\frac{1}{p_4}+\frac{1}{p_5}+\cdots$$
diverges, by a result of Euler.
If your series converged, then by Comparison so would $\sum \frac{1}{p_{3n+1}}$ and $\sum \frac{1}{p_{3n+2}}$, and therefore so would Euler's series.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use the Prime Number Theorem, that tells us $$p_{n}\sim n\log\left(n\right)$$ and so $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{p_{3n}}\sim\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{1}{n\left(\log\left(n\right)+\log\left(3\right)\right)}\sim\frac{1}{3}\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{1}{n\log\left(n\right)}$$ and the RHS diverges.